# To-infinitive or participle modifying noun?

Tags: participles, to-infinitive

What is difference between to-infinitive and participle when they modify noun like the below sentence? Is it the same meaning that using ‘distributed’ instead of ‘to be distributed’?

> Although the health information campaign is scheduled to begin tomorrow, the staff have yet to finish printing the handouts *to be distributed* at medical clinics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know the difference in meaning between **to be distrubuted** and just **distributed** in your example sentence.

The use of **to be distributed** discusses a future action.

> The staff have **yet to finish** printing the handouts **to be distributed** at medical clinics.

The handouts have *not yet* been distributed.

When using just **distributed**, however, the sentence becomes ungrammatical:

> The staff have **yet to finish** printing the handouts **distributed** at medical clinics.

**Distributed** on its own refers to a past action. But it's not possible (in this sentence construction) for something *yet to be finished* to be associated with something already completed.

To use just **distributed**, the rest of the sentence would have to be rephrased so that everything is in the past:

> The staff **finished** printing the handouts and **distributed** them at medical clinics.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *to be distributed* talks about the future plan. The usage of *to infinitive* won't serve the purpose there.

The handouts are not yet printed, therefore, the past participle is used. Had it been only *distributed,* it would not talk about the future and would denote that the action is done.

> The handouts were *distributed*

The action is done there.